# Java and operations on array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a problem with arrays in java. 
I have a array:

```
double[][] tab2 = {{318, 0.0825},
                  {321, 0.1131},
                  {309, 0.0283},
                  {319, 0.0830}};
```

and I need to change that array to:

```
double[][] tab2 = {{318, 0.0830},
                  {321, 0.0283},
                  {309, 0.1131},
                  {319, 0.0825}};
```

This is what i mean. I have four numbers. In this example 318, 321, 309 and 319. Every number is connected with another number, like 318 - 0.0825, 321 - 0.1131, etc. I need change value second values. When number which is connected with the biggest number should be connected with the smaller eg. 321 - 0.1131 should be 321 - 0.0283, 318 - 0.00830 should be 318 - 0.0825.  It is possible to do this things?

Comment: Map<Long, Double> would be better choice in this case.

Comment: A map would be a better choice; still leaves the problem of sorting though.

Comment: Simple matter of programming.  Sort the two lists separately and then update the original based on the sort results.  Ideally you'd sort the first column using an index/tag sort, so you'd directly get the index values, but for a small list it's not impractical to go back and search your original list for matches.

Comment: (Or, if the original order is not important, you could just take the two sorted lists and re-join them, taking items from the second in reverse order.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier to do this if the arrays were arranged in transposed form.

```
double[][] tab3 = {
    {318.0, 321.0, 309.0, 319.0},
    {0.0830, 0.1131, 0.0283, 0.0830}}
```

You can then sort the first array (`tab3[0]`) in ascending order and then the second array (`tab3[1]`) in descending order. Then all of the array indexes will line up and match the largest to the smallest. `double[0][0]` will be the biggest and `double[1][0]` will be the smallest, matching 309 and 0.1131 together.

```
double[][] tab3 = {
    {309.0, 318.0, 319.0, 321.0},
    {0.1131, 0.0830, 0.0830, 0.0283}}
```

Comment: This is good, but not for me. Those first numbers could be different. Number 309 could be 328, so your solution is not for me, but thx.

Comment: That's why you sort both arrays, as I explained. If you need them to be in that exact order, you could save the original positions of each one before sorting and reconstruct them later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` in this case, Specify first number as key and second number as value. Refer below document for more details about Map.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Your java doc link is too old(1.4.2). Update it to java 7.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not be the most efficient solution, but it will work

```
double[][] tab2 = {{318, 0.0825},
              {321, 0.1131},
              {309, 0.0283},
              {319, 0.0830}};
List<Double> firstEntries = new ArrayList<Double>(  );
List<Double> secondEntries = new ArrayList<Double>(  );
for ( double[] doubles : tab2 ) {
  firstEntries.add( doubles[ 0 ] );
  secondEntries.add( doubles[ 1 ] );
}
Collections.sort( firstEntries );
Collections.sort( secondEntries );
Collections.reverse( secondEntries );
//now the lists contain the entries in the correct order
//if needed, they can be grouped again in an array
for ( int i = 0; i < tab2.length; i++ ) {
  double[] doubles = tab2[ i ];
  doubles[1] = secondEntries.get( firstEntries.indexOf( doubles[0] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by:

```
HashMap<Integer,Double> mapValues = new HashMap<Integer,Double>();
// Insert keys and values into mapValues
Integer[] keys  = mapValues.KeySet().toArray(new Integer[]{});
Double[] values = mapValues.Values().toArray(new Double[]{});
Arrays.sort(keys,Collections.reverseOrder());
Arrays.sort(values);
HashMap<Integer,Double> resultMap = new HashMap<Integer,Double>();
for(int i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
   resultMap.put(keys[i], values[i]);
}
```